# Removing Terms from Patsy Formulas with re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, patsy

Context: Python 3.4.3

I'm not very good with regular expressions, and I can't seem to figure out a robust solution to this using `re`.

Suppose we have a long [patsy formula](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html) and somewhere in the middle is an expression like:

```
... + xvar + np.log(xvar)+xvar**2 + xvar2+ z...
```

Patsy formulas are just strings that follow well-behaved rules, so I'm wondering if anyone has written / can easily write a robust method for dropping specific terms from a given formula?  So, for example:

```
>>> remove_term(long_formula, 'xvar')
... + np.log(xvar)+xvar**2 + xvar2+ z...
```

and

```
>>> remove_term(long_formula, 'xvar2')
... + xvar + np.log(xvar)+xvar**2 + z...
```

etc.  This would need to also be robust to having a variable at the beginning / end of the right-hand side formula spec.

My limited regex-foo only produces things like:

```
re.sub('[^(]\s*xvar\s*',' FOUND IT ', 'y ~ xvar + np.log(xvar)')
```

Maybe a semi-complicated if/else `re.sub` situation?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Are you only looking to remove `xvar` when it's part of a series of additions/subtractions? It seems like you don't want to remove things inside parenthesis...

Comment: Try [`(?m)(?:\s*(?:^|[-+/:]|\*\*?)\s*x\s*|\s*x\s*($|[-+/:]|\*\*?)\s*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/rL6dN1/3) and replace with a space. See this [Python demo](http://ideone.com/ZEIwjy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to do what you want to do with a regular expressions, because Patsy's formula language is not a regular language. (Just like how [HTML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1925449).)

But there's no need to go messing about with strings anyway -- as [documented here](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html), patsy provides a nice object-oriented representation for formulas as part of its public API. Internally, you're using this every time you call `dmatrix`: formula strings get parsed into this representation, and then this representation is what's used for everything downstream. But you can also work with it directly, like:

```
In [3]: m = patsy.ModelDesc.from_formula("xvar + np.log(xvar)+xvar**2 + xvar2")

In [4]: m
Out[4]: 
ModelDesc(lhs_termlist=[],
          rhs_termlist=[Term([]),
                        Term([EvalFactor('xvar')]),
                        Term([EvalFactor('np.log(xvar)')]),
                        Term([EvalFactor('xvar2')])])

In [5]: m.rhs_termlist.remove(patsy.Term([patsy.EvalFactor('xvar')]))

In [6]: m
Out[6]: 
ModelDesc(lhs_termlist=[],
          rhs_termlist=[Term([]),
                        Term([EvalFactor('np.log(xvar)')]),
                        Term([EvalFactor('xvar2')])])
```

and then pass `m` to patsy functions that expect a formula, like `patsy.dmatrix(m, dataframe)`.